# Type 'Cache' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

Tags: swift, caching, decodable, encodable

I have been following the guide found [here](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/caching-in-swift/) for **Caching in Swift**.

I am currently getting the error `Type 'Cache' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'`

This makes no sense to me as I have followed the guide to the letter, I have found a couple of people using the same cache on GitHub and I believe my output matches theirs.

Why does 'Cache' not conform?

I have added the complete class as created in the tutorial below -

```swift
final class Cache<Key: Hashable, Value> {
    private let wrapped = NSCache<WrappedKey, Entry>()
    private let entryLifetime: TimeInterval
    private let dateProvider: () -> Date
    private let keyTracker = KeyTracker()

    init(dateProvider: @escaping () -> Date = Date.init,entryLifetime: TimeInterval = 12 * 60 * 60, maximumEntryCount: Int = 50) {
        self.dateProvider = dateProvider
        self.entryLifetime = entryLifetime
        wrapped.countLimit = maximumEntryCount
        wrapped.delegate = keyTracker
    }

    func insert(_ value: Value, forKey key: Key) {
        let date = dateProvider().addingTimeInterval(entryLifetime)
        let entry = Entry(key: key, value: value, expirationDate: date)
        let wrappedKey = WrappedKey(key: key)
        wrapped.setObject(entry, forKey: wrappedKey)
        keyTracker.keys.insert(key)
    }

    func value(forKey key: Key) -> Value? {
        guard let entry = wrapped.object(forKey: WrappedKey(key: key)) else { return nil }

        guard dateProvider() < entry.expirationDate else {
            //Discard expired values
            removeValue(forKey: key)
            return nil
        }
        return entry.value
    }

    func removeValue(forKey key: Key) {
        let key = WrappedKey(key: key)
        wrapped.removeObject(forKey: key)
    }
}

private extension Cache {
    final class WrappedKey: NSObject {
        let key: Key

        init(key: Key) {
            self.key = key
        }

        override var hash: Int { return key.hashValue }

        override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
            guard let value = object as? WrappedKey else { return false }
            return value.key == key
        }
    }
}

private extension Cache {
    final class Entry {
        let key: Key
        let value: Value
        let expirationDate: Date

        init(key: Key, value: Value, expirationDate: Date) {
            self.key = key
            self.value = value
            self.expirationDate = expirationDate
        }
    }
}

extension Cache {
    subscript(key: Key) -> Value? {
        get { return value(forKey: key) }
        set {
            guard let value = newValue else {
                //If nil is assigned using subscript then remove any value for that key
                removeValue(forKey: key)
                return
            }
            insert(value, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}

private extension Cache {
    final class KeyTracker: NSObject, NSCacheDelegate {
        var keys = Set<Key>()
        func cache(_ cache: NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>, willEvictObject object: Any) {
            guard let entry = object as? Entry else { return }
            keys.remove(entry.key)
        }
    }
}

extension Cache.Entry: Codable where Key: Codable, Value: Codable {}

private extension Cache {
    func entry(forKey key: Key) -> Entry? {
        guard let entry = wrapped.object(forKey: WrappedKey(key: key)) else { return nil }
        guard dateProvider() < entry.expirationDate else {
            removeValue(forKey: key)
            return nil
        }
        return entry
    }

    func insert(_ entry: Entry) {
        wrapped.setObject(entry, forKey: WrappedKey(key: entry.key))
        keyTracker.keys.insert(entry.key)
    }
}

extension Cache: Codable where Key: Codable, Value: Codable {
    convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init()

        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let entries = try container.decode([Entry].self)
        entries.forEach(insert)
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(keyTracker.keys.compactMap(entry))
    }
}

extension Cache where Key: Codable, Value: Codable {
    func saveToDisk(withName name: String, using fileManager: FileManager = .default) throws {
        let folderURLs = fileManager.urls(
            for: .cachesDirectory,
            in: .userDomainMask
        )

        let fileURL = folderURLs[0].appendingPathComponent(name + ".cache")
        let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(self)
        try data.write(to: fileURL)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Which line gives you the error? The code compile fine for me. Or is it when you are using it you get the error?

Comment: Strange, for me it is on `extension Cache: Codable where Key: Codable, Value: Codable`

Comment: I just added it to a new project and I see `Value of type 'Encoder' has no member 'singleValueContainer'` coming from `var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()` also

Comment: Do you have `import Foundation` in your file?

Comment: I do, I have added a screen shot to my post with some additional information if that helps? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think I can help you anymore since your code compiles and runs fine when I paste it into a playground and write some code to create and save a Cache instance. Only advice left is to clean and re-build your project.